# SUM of rows excluding duplicates in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows

```
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
| id | user_id | ip_address  | amount |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |       2 | 192.168.1.1 | 0.5    |
|  2 |       2 | 192.168.1.1 | 0.5    |
|  3 |       2 | 192.168.1.2 | 0.5    |
|  4 |       2 | 192.168.1.3 | 0.5    |
|  5 |       5 | 192.168.5.1 | 1.5    |
|  6 |       5 | 192.168.5.1 | 1.5    |
|  7 |       5 | 192.168.5.3 | 0.5    |
+----+---------+-------------+--------+
```

I want to get unique `ip_address` SUM of `amount` and count duplicates as only one.

From above table there are 7 rows from which first 4 records are for `user_id` 2 and last 3 records for `user_id` 5.

I am trying to SUM of amount field along with user_id in descending order and want output as follows.

```
user_id    total_amount
5          2.0
2          1.5
```

Comment: `SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) AS total_amount FROM (SELECT user_id, amount WHERE 1 GROUP BY user_id) WHERE 1 GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select user_id, sum(amount)
from (select user_id, ip_address, amount
      from  tab 
      group by  ip_address, amount ) A
group by  user_id
order by  user_id desc
```

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6edba/3/0) Demo**

Answer (score 2):

GROUP BY, with aggregate function `SUM`, on the DISTINCT rows:

```
select user_id, sum(amount) as total_amount
from (select distinct user_id, ip_address, amount
      from tablename) t
group by user_id
```

Not sure if this is MySQL, but test and comment!

Comment: This seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use a sub query for this:

```
SELECT inner_query.user_id, SUM(inner_query.amount) FROM (
    SELECT * FROM  table_name GROUP BY user_id, ip_address ORDER BY user_id DESC 
) AS inner_query GROUP BY inner_query.user_id ORDER BY user_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want I believe:

```
SELECT USER_ID, SUM(amount) AS Amount, COUNT(*) AS [COUNT] from
(SELECT DISTINCT user_id, ip_address, amount FROM mytable)q
GROUP BY q.user_id
```